# Save R-squared from lm summary as a dataframe

Tags: r, regression, lm, summary

I want to save the result of a lm model into a dataframe. I generated an empty dataframe (Startframe), where I want to save the results.

My dataframe containing the data is called testdata in this case. It contains the Date in the first column and then several Stations in the rest of the colums.

So far this code is working to get the Estimate, Std. Error, t value and Pr(>|t|).

```
for(i in 2:ncol(testdata)) {
  x <- testdata[,1]
  y <- testdata[,i]
  mod <- lm(y ~ x)
  summary(mod)

  Startframe[i,] <- c(i,
                 summary(mod)[['coefficients']]['(Intercept)','Estimate'],
                 summary(mod)[['coefficients']]['x','Estimate'],
                 summary(mod)[['coefficients']]['x','Std. Error'],
                 summary(mod)[['coefficients']]['x','t value'],
                 summary(mod)[['coefficients']]['x','Pr(>|t|)'])
```

But how can I also extract the r.squared?

I tried to add summary(mod)[['r.squared']] to the list, but it gives me the wrong numbers.

I know str(summary(mod)) gives me an overview, but I cant figure out how to add it into my loop.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it have to be in a loop? Can I suggest another solution using `broom` package?

Comment: I would like to have it in that loop, because I am already working successfully with it, but I am also open for other options if they are working well.

Comment: I used in another context `model <- lm(Pegel$D00 ~ Pegel$dss)` and later `r2 = round(summary(model)$r.squared, 2)`

Comment: This gives me the same wrong number than my summary(mod)[['r.squared']]. I dont know why this happens.

Comment: Try `summary(t)['r.squared']$r.squared`

Comment: This is also the same. It gives me the same output as summary(mod)[['r.squared']] or round(summary(model)$r.squared, 2), but the numer is not the one I get when I control it with summary (lm(column ~ Date, data= testdata))

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found the mistake now!! Its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice way to work with the same model on different datasets is to use the `tidyverse` approach using `broom` package.

In this example I'm using the `diamonds` dataset to test how carat and depth effects the diamonds' price in different diamond cuts.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(broom)

diamonds %>% 
  nest(-cut) %>% 
  mutate(model = purrr::map(data, function(x) { 
    lm(price ~ carat + depth, data = x)}), 
    values = purrr::map(model, glance), 
    r.squared = purrr::map_dbl(values, "r.squared"), 
    pvalue = purrr::map_dbl(values, "p.value")) %>% 
  select(-data, -model, -values)

 cut       r.squared pvalue
  <ord>         <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Ideal         0.867      0
2 Premium       0.856      0
3 Good          0.851      0
4 Very Good     0.859      0
5 Fair          0.746      0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont get how this should loop over my dataframe from colums 2-10.

Comment: It's instead of using a loop

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)